# Using NSFetchedResultController with no sorting

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

1) I wanna display my search results in the same order returned by the web Service, but it seems 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors'.

2) I still wanna use a NSFetchedResultsController because I allow user to sort by date, etc, but if no sorting is chosen I want to display them in the exact order I got them.

3) Another thing, depending on the search, the items might have different priority. Since I store every item, I cannot just create a priority for each since it won't apply to every case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas,

If you want to enforce an order, then you need an attribute to sort against. I suggest you add a serial number to your model and bump it as you insert items.

Andrew

Comment: that's what I'm gonna do. I'll add this attribute and update only the order each time user performs a search.